# Add an element to existing json in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 Json object as follows.

```
var j1={"fname":"XYZ","lname":"qwe"};
```

and

```
var j2 = {"id":"10"}
```

I want to merge `j1` and `j2`

I tried with `var ob = angular.merge({},j1,j2);` 
but its showing angular.merge is not a function

I tried with `push` and `concat`. But these also gave same kind of error.

please help,
thank you.

Comment: var merged = jQuery.extend(true, j1, j2)

Comment: how about `var ob = angular.extend({}, j1, j2)`; Also what version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Angular does not support `angular.merge` yet, you can use `angular.extend` instead.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function(){
  var j1 = {"fname":"XYZ","lname":"qwe"};
  var j2 = {"id": 10};
  var obj = angular.extend({}, j1, j2);
  
  console.log(obj);
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController">
</div>
```

Note: `angular.merge` is only available from version 1.4 to the latest

Comment: Thank you But instead of `{}` I used an object

Comment: yes, you can do that as well. `angular.extend(anotherobject, j1, j2)`;